# PHPMailer inserts '=' equal sign every 75th character

Tags: php, phpmailer

Using PHPMailer 5.2.14, emails are sent in text/html.  The outgoing text is littered with equal signs every 75th character.

I tried using the [EOL workaround](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/464), but it did not remove the extra equal signs:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'from@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'FromUser';
$email->AddAddress( 'to@example.com' );
$email->Subject   = 'This is a test';
$email->IsHTML(true);
$email->Body = "<p>This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; </p>";

// fix EOL here? 
$email->LE = PHP_EOL;

$email->Send();
```

Resulting source upon receipt:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"><font face="arial"><base href="http://example.com/"><!-- </base> -->=
<p>This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This i=
s a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.=
&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; Th=
is is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a t=
est.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp;=
 </p></font>
```

The equal signs appear when viewing in Outlook.    When I send the same text/html to a gmail account, the equal signs are not present.

What needs to happen to eliminate these stray equal signs for recipients using Outlook?

Comment: Please reduce the size of your text, we don't need so many lines to understand that there are `=`. What code do you use to encode the text?

Comment: Please suggest an appropriate sub if asking php questions is not appropriate here.

Comment: Again for the individuals voting to close this question as off topic, please suggest the appropriate sub rather than silently killing the question.   I would also recommend not closing this as the tag `PHPMailer` has been used ''2055'' times as of this reply.

Comment: if this `$email->AddAddress( 'to@example.com );` is part of your real code, it's missing a quote and is throwing off Stack's syntax highlighting. Which should read as `$email->AddAddress( 'to@example.com' );`

Comment: Plus, instead of giving us a few morsels, why not post more code and what you're sending as HTML.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, that's a type-o here.  The code has the correct quoting.

Comment: I've added the entire block of code to the question.

Comment: might even be a local issue and certain settings in Outlook. Far as I can see, you have meta that belong in <head> and have <font> that belongs in <body> etc. etc. If there isn't proper HTML document structuring, then something will complain for sure. Including a valid doctype.

Comment: I'll add <body> tags and retest.

Comment: Here's what your document should look like: `<!DOCTYPE html><head>meta stuff and <base href...></head><body>HTML stuff</body></html>` anything outside that and not conforming to HTML, will break.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, adding the html and body tags worked.   If you'll add this as an answer I'll credit you appropriately.

Comment: It has been done. Glad to hear this one was solved, *cheers*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem with html-emails in PHPMailer. I've tested different things and found out:

- The problem happens if the message has a special length - in my case >1002 letters in one line (when I have removed some letters (irrelevant which ones) the email was correct)
- The problem is visible only in some email-programms (e.g. MS Outlook, website t-online.de; no problems with yahoo)
- I've testet PHPMailer 5.2.7 - 5.2.14: The problem exists in PHPMailer >5.2.10 (no problems in PHPMailer 5.2.7 - 5.2.10)
- Solutions like '$mail->Encoding = "7bit";' or '$mail->LE = PHP_EOL;' didn't worked for me
- No Problems when sending the email via isSmtp().
- Tested on two different servers: Server 1 contains equal signs, Server 2 doesn't contain that signs but has wrong linebreaks - the php-configuration on both servers is nearly identical > it doesn't seem to be a php-problem

So for me the solution was "take PHPMailer 5.2.10" till they solve the problem in a newer version - No good solution, but it works for me till I find a better one ;-)

Comment: 5.2.10 fixed the problem.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is known as [quoted-printable encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) and is quite common in email messages. The equal sign is used as an escape character, and line lengths are limited to 76 characters. If Outlook is not recognizing this, you may have to manually set headers telling it that it's encoded in this fashion.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what your document should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   meta stuff and <base href...>
</head>
    <body>
    HTML stuff
    </body>
</html>
```

Anything outside that and not conforming to HTML, will put a damper on your day.

Far as I can see, you have meta that belong in `<head>` and have `<font>` tags that belongs in `<body>` etc. etc. If there isn't proper HTML document structuring, then something will complain for sure. Including a valid doctype.

A quick sidenote about the `<font>` tag; it's in deprecation.

You could use inline CSS styling instead. Do not use `<style>` tags as most Email clients will throw that out and ignore it.

Comment: I don't know why this has been chosen as the correct answer. While it's good advice, it's nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @Synchro [Read OP's comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787777/phpmailer-inserts-equal-sign-every-75th-character/33788388?noredirect=1#comment55343609_33787777). It has everything to do with it. Do look at their code too and the message they're trying to send.

Comment: Fred's answer is solid but SusiMage's answer below (posted yesterday) is now marked as the selected answer.  See his/her post for why.

Comment: @acoder Glad to see you have your solution, *cheers* - I gave it an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

With `'$mail->Encoding = 'base64';` it works for us now with v5.2.17.
Hopefully this is finally fixed in v6.

Answer (score -1):

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'from@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'FromUser';
$email->AddAddress( 'to@example.com' );
$email->Subject   = 'This is a test';
$email->IsHTML(true);
$email->Body = "<p>This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&`enter code here`nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; This is a test.&nbsp; </p>";

// fix EOL here? 
$email->LE = PHP_EOL;

$email->Send();
```